# Импорт файлов Python

Tags: python, python-import

я пишу проект на fast api и столкнулся с проблемой.

```
корневая папка:
main.py
database.py
config.py

accounts - init.py
         -router.py
         -security.py
```

как в роутер импортировать database?

Comment: Вот так импортировать из родительской директории `from .. import database`

Comment: from корень.database import db

Comment: @Bol4onok какой ещё `корень`?

Comment: @PeterKolosov зачастую ее называют src, корневая папка, где хранится код приложения.